# Android: How to get rid of the header bar in App?

Tags: android, layout, titlebar

For some reasons when I launch the app in the splash activity and in the row activity, see images, there is a header bar with the name of the app "Baby Read".
I don't want the header there, how do I get rid of it?
Splash Activity
[image]

Row Activity
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

This is the splash layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/babyreadappsplash"
    >

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="90px"
        android:layout_height="90px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10px"
        android:layout_marginTop="10px"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"

        >
    </TextView>
```

This is res/values/styles after adding the code suggested
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

And this is the manifest after adding the code suggested
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Create a style for your splash Activity like this

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    </style>
```

after that set this style for your splash Activity in `Manifest`

```
<activity
            android:name="activity name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
             />
```

**Update**
make your style like this

```
<style name="splashStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    //add other attributes
    </style>
```

if not work for you change the parent of your `AppTheme` to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar`

Comment: I don't know how to create a style in my splash activity. I thought that styles belong in the res/values folder.

Comment: yes, of course, to go  `res/values/styles` and put the style, after that go to `AndroidManifest.xml` and add this `android:name="activity name"` line to your spash activity

Comment: I did put it in res/values/styles but the word windowActionBar stayed red meaning there is an error.

Comment: did you make sure to put it inside `<resources>` tag?

Comment: Please look at the screenshots that I added above.

Comment: check the answer I updated it, and let me know if works or not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201402/discussion-between-jimale-abdi-and-user3814312).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in `onCreate`:

```
  getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: I put that code in the onCreate and it didn't work, is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

No need to create anew theme (At least for this purpose)

- Modify you app theme (Picture one)change `parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"` for `parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"`
- On you manifest, in the application section (picture 2)add

  ```
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
  ```

If by any change you are supporting APIs below 13 you can add

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

to your app theme rather than changing the parent.

As a side note I would advise moving from Holo themes to Appcompat or even Material, but that´s out of the scope of this question

Comment: DISCLAIMER: by adding to the application tag as I suggested you get rid of the bar in all of your activities. You can add the same line on individual activities